# How to parse Lucene Boolean Query?

Tags: lucene

I have the `toString()` output from a `org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery` object, but the `SimpleQueryParser` doesn't seem to accept it.   It seems to not accept the hash character `#` in the query:

```
+(#(title:bi title:"business intelligence"))
```

The query above has the hash (`#`) ignored when reparsing it, which I think is being stripped by the StandardAnalyzer.

My question is: how do I parse the toString() reprepsentation of a BooleanQuery reliably?

Comment: Can you show us your `BooleanQuery` code? Can you show us how it generates a `#` when you use `toString()`? What version of Lucene are you using?

Comment: Can you also clarify what you mean by "_the `SimpleQueryParser` doesn't seem to accept it_"? In other words, why are you trying to use `SimpleQueryParser` with the `toString()` output from a boolean query?

Comment: I don't have the booleanQuery Object, I'm trying to parse the Lucene syntax produced from calling the `_validate` endpoint of ElasticSearch, which converts ES query syntax to Lucene syntax.  Unfortunately it just outputs the toString form.

Comment: @andrewJames:  If you parse the query above, it's not in the (a?) query syntax supported by Lucene.  The `#` character is not one of the tokens, so it gets removed in the analyzer pass.   As a result, the queries no longer match the same document, since `#` is not treated as an AND .  I don't want to pull in too much context; the core of it is BooleanQuery.toString() outputs a syntax not the same as a parser can understand.  See my comment above for why I am am using the toString() form.

Comment: So ElasticSearch is _not_ producing a valid Lucene query...? That sounds more like an ElasticSearch question, not a core Lucene question. But I confess I probably have misunderstood what you are doing. Thank you for the clarifications, anyway.

Comment: Another way of forming this question: how to convert from a BooleanQuery to a parseable Lucene Syntax query?   If the toString() serialization is not correct, what is the right way?